# TypeError: fs.writeFileSyns is not a function

Tags: node.js

TypeError: fs.writeFileSyns is not a function

```
var fs = require("fs");

var newFile = fs.readFileSync("readMe.txt", "utf8");
fs.writeFileSyns("writeMe.txt", newFile);
```

Comment: did you mean `writeFileSync`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code, it should be `fs.writeFileSync("writeMe.txt", newFile);`,

```
var fs = require("fs");

var newFile = fs.readFileSync("readMe.txt", "utf8");
fs.writeFileSync("writeMe.txt", newFile);
```